# Set a disabled TextBox's ForeColor to be the same as its BackColor in C#

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface

How do I set a disabled TextBox's current text color to be the same as its current background color in C#?

Simply doing txtLala.ForeColor = txtLala.BackColor does not seems to work.

Comment: Can I ask why you want to do this?

(there might be an easier approach to achieve the results you are looking for)

Comment: Actually all I wanted to achieve is to make the text box appears to be value-less. For some reason I can't just set its .Text to empty because this will incur too big a change in other places and I would rather not go that path.

Comment: Is this ASP or winforms?

Comment: Put that second comment as an EDIT please. You should use the Add.Attributes method described below

Answer (score 3):

This works:

```
txtLala.Text = "Red";
txtLala.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
txtLala.ForeColor = txtLala.BackColor;
txtLala.ReadOnly = true;
```

Try setting the `color`, before the `readonly`. And also check how you are setting the color!

**EDIT**

Try this

```
txtLala.Attributes.Add("style","background-color:Red;color:Red");
```

If you are trying to make it invisible, you know you can set it as

```
txtLala.Visible = False;
```

**EDIT II**

I finally tried

```
txtLala.Enabled = false;
```

... you see that grey shadow color! I don't think you can mess with that, it looks to be a browser property setting.

Why not set as `ReadOnly` or `Visible = False`?

Maybe you have a good reason for `Enabled = false`

But you should note:

> Use the Enabled property to specify or determine whether a control is functional. **When set to false, the control appears dimmed**, preventing any input from being entered in the control.
>
>   
> Note The ability to enable or disable functionality is always available. **However, dimming and locking the control only works in Microsoft Internet Explorer version 4 and later.**
>
>   
> This property propagates down the control hierarchy. Therefore, disabling a container control will disable all child controls within that container.
>
>    
> Note  Not all controls support this property. See the indivual controls for details.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a readonly textbox, you need to explicitly set your BackColor first, then your statement will work.

```
txtLala.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Info;
txtLala.ForeColor = txtLala.BackColor;
```

Ref: http://bytes.com/groups/net-c/233961-read-only-textbox

Then again, if it's readonly, a label might be better. If you're trying to hide it, perhaps setting `.Visible = false` would be better still.

---

**Edit**: This seems to be a [common question](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=Enabled+false+textbox+font+color+change&btnG=Search) on the web. With respect to **winforms**: [This site](http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/showthread.php?t=296536) suggests dropping the box into a frame and setting `Enabled = false` *on the frame, not the textbox*. Once you do that, you may be able to maintain control of the forecolor.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to only work for TextBox that is read only. If it is disabled (.Enabled = false). It does not seems to work.

Comment: it is c#, yes, what he says is true.

Comment: C# could mean ASP.NET or Winforms... the difference is important

Comment: Ah ok, I'm leaning to Winforms too.